# How to calc svg text element bounding box in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, svg, jsdom

[image: It's a demo svg like this]

FontSize is 60, but the bounding box shows that render height is 84px. How to use fontFamily or lineHeight or other way to calc it in nodejs server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need something that has a full SVG parsing and rendering engine.

There may be a node SVG library that I am unaware of.  But I think you'll likely need to use something like [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer).
Which is an API which lets you control a headless version of Chrome.